# Can the spirit of a destroyed Sentient Weapon be recovered by Divine Intervention?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, intelligent-magic-items

So, I'm in a 5th edition party that just finished up Rise of Tiamat.

We defeated the Dragon Goddess, but our Barbarian's sentient weapon, Hazirawn, sacrificed himself to stop her from re-entering the material realm.

As a War Cleric of Tempus, could I use Divine Intervention to request that Tempus locate the spirit of the fallen weapon and recover it so the weapon could be repaired and his soul returned to it?

My cleric is currently 15th level. I have discussed this with my DM, and she says that she isn't sure if it would work

Comment: What level is your cleric? Welcome to RPGSE. The [tour], [ask] and [answer] are useful guides on how to get the most out of this Q&A site.  Also, have you discussed this your DM yet?

Comment: My cleric is currently 15th level. I have discussed this with my GM, and she says that she isn't sure if it would work.

Comment: Please add that detail into your question.  I've edited that in for you; :-)  that kind of detail matters in getting you a best answer.

Answer (score 7):

### It boils down to a GM choice

The Divine Intervention feature is almost entirely GM dependent. If you get the 15% roll after using the feature, the following effect is presented:

> The DM chooses the nature of the intervention; the effect of any cleric spell or cleric domain spell would be appropriate.

No cleric spell, or cleric domain spell would have the effect you desire, so it would be the GM's fiat entirely if, how, and to what extent Tempus would choose to/be able to intervene.

### Sentient Magic Items

The rules on sentient magic items are fairly vague on how these items are created, or if restoring them is possible. The *Dungeon Master's Guide* says:

> Some magic items possess sentience and personality. Such an item might be possessed, haunted by the spirit of a previous owner, or self-aware thanks to the magic used to create it.

As far as I can tell, it is not clear which of these, if any, has resulted in Hazirawn's sentient from the adventure module, so even if we could reproduce the conditions of its sentience, we wouldn't know which conditions to reproduce. Again, this would boil down to a GM decision on if/how it were possible to reconstitute a sentient weapon, deity or not.

### A look at Tempus from a lore perspective

Tempus is a neutral deity, and a god of war. He is well known as a proponent of honorable battles, and especially, honorable/courageous deaths in battle. If Hazirawn sacrificed himself in such a way, Tempus would almost surely respect that sacrifice (a battle against Tiamat is surely a courageous endeavor).

Because of these facts, I don't think the Divine Intervention question is about whether Tempus would honor the request, but whether he is able to. [Dan B's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/168146/41726) goes into this a bit, and there are certainly many reasons why a deity would be unable to access the soul/spirit/consciousness of Hazirawn to restore the sword to your barbarian party member.

That being said, I'm sure it is within Tempus' power, as a greater deity, to restore the magical properties of the greatsword. He also, almost surely, could place some sort of sentience in the sword, even if the original sentience is beyond his reach. Perhaps the new sentience of the blade is that of one of Tempus' deceased followers whose soul resides in his realm and is willing to return to the living in some fashion to partake in further battles.

Of course, Tempus' behavior is once again up to the GM, so she is the only one who can answer your question for your group's campaign.

Comment: Awesome final suggestion about a different soul going into the blade

Answer (score 6):

## It's up to your DM

Your DM decides whether your deity is capable of doing this thing for you, and your DM decides whether your deity is willing to do it for you.  If your DM wants this to work, it will work; if your DM doesn't want this to work, it won't work.

Your DM might give you any of the following objections:

- maybe Hazirawn's soul is busy sealing the portal to Tiamat, and if Hazirawn is brought back then Tiamat can invade
- maybe the ritual destroyed Hazirawn's soul, or gave it into Tiamat's control where your god can't reach it
- maybe your deity has noticed that Hazirawn is Neutral Evil in alignment and doesn't want you to have it
- maybe your DM feels that this will be a better story if Hazirawn isn't part of the game (because it was too powerful, or too evil, or for some other reason)

If I were you, I'd probably be suspicious that the DM had arranged the "Hazirawn sacrifices itself to seal the portal" plot point on purpose because your DM didn't want Hazirawn to be in the game any more.

I'd go ahead and try the divine intervention just for roleplaying reasons -- there doesn't seem to be much harm in it, even if it fails.  But I'd expect that it would probably fail.